# Ask - How to add text in front of background image inside card

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

So, I develop React Native App using NativeBase as my Component framework.
I'm using card component.
This is my codes:

```
render(){
    return(
      <View>
          <View style={[styles.cardWrapper]}>
            <Card>
              <CardItem>
                <Image style={{ resizeMode: 'repeat', width: null }} source={require('../../assets/bg_1.jpg')} />
              </CardItem>
              <CardItem>
                <Icon name='ios-musical-notes' style={{color : '#ED4A6A'}} />
                <Text>Listen now</Text>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
          </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

This is my css:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardWrapper:{
    padding: 20,
  }
});
```

I want to put some text in front of background image layer, something like this:
[image]
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
<CardItem>
    <Image
      style={{ resizeMode: 'repeat', paddingTop: 60, width: null }}
      source={require('../../assets/bg_1.jpg')}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', backgroundColor: 'transparent', color: '#fff' }}>Holla</Text>
    </Image>
</CardItem>
```

This works for both, iOS and Android

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
<CardItem>
    <Image
      style={{ resizeMode: 'repeat', width: null }}
      source={require('../../assets/bg_1.jpg')}>
        <Text>Holla</Text>
    </Image>
</CardItem>
```

Comment: I already tried that, but the result doesnt work as I expected. This is the result : https://s18.postimg.org/csflvk021/Screen_Shot_2016_10_03_at_5_05_30_PM.png

Comment: Yes i checked it again.
It works fine for Android only